# What's the appropriate word for "ending a streak"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the verb that best fits this situation.

> You promise yourself not to eat chocolate for 7 days. However, on the fifth day, you eat it. You could say you *interrupted* the streak.

Is there a more elegant and appropriate word to replace *interrupted* in the sentence above?

Comment: elegance is so subjective, but 'busted' or 'broke' are certainly idiomatically appropriate options at least

Comment: The video-game based neologism ["C-C-C-COMBO BREAKER!"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/combo-breaker) comes to mind.

Comment: Before that, is 'streak' the most appropriate word in this context?  I know of a 'winning streak' or a 'losing streak', but have never heard it employed in quite this way; and such use is not in my dictionary. The only metaphorical use of streak I know is about running naked in public.

Answer (score 3):

Streaks can be **"broken"** or **"stopped"** or **"halted"** or **"ended"**.

Answer (score 3):

Streaks are commonly referred to in [sports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Losing_streak). Your home-town team could **snap**, **break** or **end** a losing streak.

Using **interrupted** may not fit, because it implies that there is another streak to come.

Usually **streak** is associated with a series of discrete events rather than non-events such as avoiding chocolate. I don't know why- since streaks (as on glass) are blurred together rather than being discontinuous. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of reforming habits, **fell of the wagon** fits. The term is most commonly identified with lapses in recovery from alcoholism, but can fit other contexts.

> You promise yourself not to eat chocolate for 7 days. However, on the fifth day, you fall over the wagon and eat it.

Answer (score -1):

You failed and you want to put a positive spin on it, hmm, you achieved your target early perhaps.